# Munkres, Chapter 2, Section 21, Exercise 8, pag. 134. Proof verification.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y$ be a metric space. Let $f_n : X \to Y$ be a sequence of continuous functions. Let $x_n$ be a sequence of points of $X$ converging to $x$. Show that if the sequence $( f_n )$ converges uniformly to $f$, then $( f_n(x_n) )$ converges to $f(x)$.

I want to know if the following resolution is ok.

Let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $d$ be a metric for the space $Y$. Let $B_d(f(x), \epsilon / 2)$ be a ball centered at $f(x)$. By Theorem 21.6, the function $f$ is continuous, and then $U = f^{-1}(B_d(f(x), \epsilon / 2))$ is open in $X$. Since the sequence $( x_n )$ converges to $x$ and $x \in U$, there is a positive integer $N_1$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \ge N_1$. Hence, $f(x_n) \in B_d(f(x), \epsilon / 2)$ for all $n \ge N_1$. Now, let $B_d(f(x_n), \epsilon / 2)$ be a ball centered at each $f(x_n) \in B_d(f(x), \epsilon / 2)$. Given that $( f_n )$ converges uniformly to $f$, there is a positive integer $N_2 \ge N_1$ such that $f_n(x_n) \in B_d(f(x_n), \epsilon / 2)$ for all $n \ge N_2$. Since by the Triangle inequality each ball $B_d(f(x_n), \epsilon / 2) \subset B_d(f(x), \epsilon)$, it follows that $f_n(x_n) \in B_d(f(x), \epsilon)$ for all $n \ge N_2$. Therefore, the sequence $( f_n(x_n) )$ converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes, it looks okay.